# Fallback method for translation

Tags: symfony

Is it possible to have a fallback method for an translation that's not found in the messages catalog?

I have `"wave.transition.delete_tasks.display"|trans` and instead of returning that string, I want to return "Delete Tasks".

I could run a cleanup after every call, e.g.

```
"wave.transition.delete_tasks.display"|trans|cleanup
```

where `cleanup` does exactly that, but I was hoping for a hook where I could always run it.

My current plan is to combine `|trans|cleanup` into `|clean_trans`, and running the translation lookup in the Twig filter, but would prefer an easier way.

Comment: Couldn't you just add the translation to the translation file?

Comment: Make english translation and imagine that it's the fallback.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @malcolm you could just use plain English as your key for translation, like that :

```
"Delete Tasks"|trans
```

And then, in your `messages.fr.yml` or equivalent, do :

```
messages:
  Delete Tasks: "Supprimer les tâches"
```

Comment: this is asking for trouble, sometimes the English words for different contexts is the same, but in other languages you would need them to be different...

Comment: Well then, add an English translation file .. it's still the simplest way